# Only one row echoed

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code. I  only get one one row echoed the first one.

What do ido wrong?

```
<?php
include("/connectdb.php");
$link2=Connection();
$rt = mysql_query("SELECT motion FROM tempLog WHERE Id='13007423' AND DATE(`timeStamp`) = CURDATE() ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 2", $link2);
$result = mysql_fetch_row($rt);
if($result)
echo $result[0];
echo $result[1];
?>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP v5.5 and have been removed as of v7.0. They should not be used for new code and should be swapped out for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) equivalents as soon as possible.

Comment: You need to loop the rows, right now you're just fetching one. Also, some brackets are in order after `if ($result)`

Comment: mysql_fetch_row will only, as the name suggests, return a row, that row will contain an array of values you request, so you're $result[0] will return whatever the column "motion" contains, you probably want while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rtf)) { echo $row[0]; }

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php read the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_fetch_row() returns only one line of your query. So you only have an array with your 'mention' variable.

Use this to print all your lines :

```
$rt = mysql_query("SELECT motion FROM tempLog WHERE Id='13007423' AND DATE(`timeStamp`) = CURDATE() ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 2", $link2);
while ($result =  mysql_fetch_row($rt)) {
    echo $result[0];
}
```

And please, use mysqli_ . mysql_ is deprecated since php5.5 and removed in php7.0

Answer (score 0):

mysql is deprecated  and you should migrate to mysqli or PDO

anyway  you shot iterate over the result

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rt)) {

    echo $result[0];

    echo '<br />';
}
```